# Can a smart battery charger power a 12V windscreen wiper motor?

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor

I have a very old windscreen motor attached to a rotisserie which I would like to run. I was told that I need a battery charger, but most of the ones I can find are "smart" ones. I have a 2A smart charger and it doesn't work, reading a bit more it seems I need 10A capacity to start the motor while 'stalled'.

My question is does the charger have to be one that can explicitly run 12V appliances? E.g.

https://www.projecta.com.au/battery-charger-products/12v-automatic-10a-7-stage-battery-charger

or, can I get this intelligent charger with 7 modes?

https://www.supercheapauto.com.au/p/sca-sca-12v-10-amp-7-stage-battery-charger/544706.html

I have no idea what the stages in the specifications quoted below are:

| SCA 12V 10 Amp 7 Stage Battery Charger |  |
| --- | --- |
| Chemistry Types: | Standard Lead Acid / AGM / GEL / Calcium |
| Stages: | 1: Primary Analysis (Desulphation) / 2: Soft Start / 3: Bulk Charge / 4: Absorption / 5: |
| Voltage: | 12V |
| Start Voltage: | 0 Volts |
| Amperage: | 10A |
| Protections: | Surge / Reverse Polarity / Overload / Short Circuit |
| Suitability: | Batteries up to 1100CCA / 100AH |
| Warranty: | 12 months |

Comment: It sounds like you need a power supply rather than a battery charger. A smart battery charger expects to find a battery at the end of its leads. If it doesn't behave like a battery, then the charger may shut down to avoid damaging the battery. An old style battery charger was dumb, more like a power supply.

Comment: thanks @Neil_UK that is what I suspect. So why is it that all the smart battery chargers are much cheaper than the the battery charger that can be a power supply?

Comment: Cheaper probably because they don’t use a big transformer and components used are cheap so they don’t last long.

Comment: So get a battery to go with the smart charger. Battery size depends on run time…

Comment: @SolarMike I do not understand your comment, do you mean I should attach my smart charger to a battery and then run crocodile clips from the battery to my windscreen wiper motor?

Comment: You just need a 12V power supply. It should be easy to find one. They're cheap and common. A PC power supply is one example. It won't need to supply 10A since the motor won't draw that unless it has a heavy load. You'll probably need more like 3A.

Comment: @Drew I cannot find a 12V supply which outputs to crocodile clamps, are these readily available? The motor was modified to turn a heavy rotisserie, the total weight is probably about 6 kgs.

Comment: You don't need crocodile clamps. You can just hook up the wires with wire nuts or solder, or 100 other ways. You can even buy croc clips with a screw terminal on the back to attach a wire. Just get some electrical tape and a pair of wire strippers and wing it, you'll figure it out.

Comment: @Drew lack of electrical knowledge was what led me to the point of buying a 2A smart charger, which didn't work, and then nearly a 10A smart charger, which probably will not work. I will be looking for a dumb charger. Thank you all of you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery smart charger takes samples of voltage and/or current, to sense the status of the battery, and uses sample data to control the charging output. This is why a smart charger is not suited to drive a motor.

Wiper motor hobby page describes typical power sources:

http://www.scary-terry.com/wipmtr/wipmtr.htm

Sites listed on the hobby page that sell power sources to drive wiper motors:

https://www.monsterguts.com/store/

https://www.frightprops.com/

Answer (score 2):

A modern, smart battery charger would be most unsuitable to run a car windshield wiper motor.

However, a simple 12V battery charger of yore, with a charging current of 3.5A or higher, would do. Such chargers would have transformers with 'high impedance' secondaries in order to limit the charging current.

Alternatively, all that would be required to rig up a power supply would be a 12 V transformer and a bridge rectifier of adequate current rating.

A car windshield wiper motor would generally draw less than 3A on load.

One would do well to measure the wiper motor current on load, when powered by a 12 V battery, before taking a decision on the required power supply current rating.

Comment: Would be better to say "measure the wiper motor current on load *and the stall (start-up) current*" as PSU will need to deliver that, too. Good answer anyway, upvoted.

Comment: Thank you, Tony, sure slip-up indeed!